# How does measurement protocol work for internal promotions with multiple promos

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have been trying to use measurement protocol to send data to google analytics and I had stumbled upon the point on how to send the hit for Internal Promotions. The Measurement Protocol offers `promo$id`, `promo$nm`, `promo$cr` and `promo$ps` for the individual promos and `promoa` for Promotion Action. Now if I have to send multiple promotion data i would have my url as:

```
www.google-analytics.com/batch?
     v=1
    &tid=UA-XXXXXX-Y
    &t=event
    &promoa=click
    &promo1id=1234
    &promo1nm=SummerSale
    &promo2id=2345
    &promo2name=WinterSale
```

But when I hit this only my last promotion's details are getting displayed and not both.
Could someone help me with this. Is the way I am sending the request wrong?

Comment: Are actually trying to send multiple clicks in one hit? Or is that a typo, and you are actually trying to send multiple impressions?

Comment: I am trying to send multiple promotional events in one click